# How to highlight an item of a listview programmatically?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview and I need to highlight a item programmatically.

I tried with this:

```
CalendarList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.CalendarList);
CalendarList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, MyApplication.roundMatches(CalendarPicker.getValue())));

CalendarList.setSelection(2);
```

but setSelection didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally none of these solutions works, i did this by a different way, changing the colour of the text of the selected item

Answer (score 3):

To highlight an item in touch mode you have to first call           CalendarList.requestFocusFromTouch(); then CalendarList.setSelection(2);

In touch mode setSelection() doesn't work by itself.

Answer (score 1):

You want the highlighting on click?

Then override the `onItemClickedListener()`

and do this inside:

```
position = position - listview.getFirstVisibleItem();
listview.getChildAt(position).requestFocus();
```

or make use of `<selector`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override onScroll() method:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView listView, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    /* Get view of item in list */
    View view = listView.getSelectedView();
    }
```

When have view object of list view you can change what ever you want, notice you must implement code for handle when lost focus.

Otherwise, i think have another solution is change color of item via implement of Adapter.
Regards,

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand this answer, i dont want to select with scroll, i want to select programatically, for example:  
CalendarList.setSelection(2);

Comment: Sorry, How about that: adaptview.getChildAt(2).setSelected(true);